# Resultant Lift Direction Confusion

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Quite a small scale question but I have gotten myself confused. Inside Ansys Fluent I am simulating a wing at different angle of attacks, instead of rotating the airfoil I have rotated the inlet velocity, into its X and Y components as such that the flow will enter from a slight angle below the airfoi like so.

[image: flow direction]

which would make X direction `COS(AoA)` and Y Direction `SIN(AoA)`
now heres where I've gotten myself stuck. when calculating lift force which is perpendicular to the flow, this requires a resultant force triangle to the left.

[image: lift direction]

Now I cant decide whether it should be `X = -SIN(AoA)` and `Y = COS(AoA)` to resolve for lift